# How to prove that $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|~~\text{Im}(iz)>0\}$ is open in $(\mathbb{C},d)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that $$S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|~~\text{Im}(iz)>0\}$$ is open in $(\mathbb{C},d)$?

I know I need to find a $B_{r}(z) \subset \{z \in\mathbb{C}\mid~~\text{Im}(iz)>0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Put $z=x+iy,$ so that $iz=-y+ix$ and so $\text{Im}(iz)=x=\text{Re}(z)$. This holds for all $z\in\Bbb C$. The idea here is to pick a point $z$ in $S$--that is, a point somewhere to the right of the imaginary axis (why?)--and make a circle small enough around $z$ so that every point in the circle is also to the right of the imaginary axis. How can we choose the radius of such a circle? Try drawing a picture.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$S=\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}|~~\text{Im}(iz)>0\}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|~~x=\mathrm{Re(z)}>0\}$$
Since $\mathbb{C}$ is homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ then we can see that $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*_+\times\mathbb{R}$ which is open.